# MongoDB group aggregation with condition in $sum

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Collection of my database is something like below

```
[{ 
   _id:1,
   status:"active",
   sale: 4,
   createdAt:"2019-10-08 08:46:19"
},
{
   _id:2,
   status:"inactive",
   sale:5,
   createdAt:"2019-10-08 06:41:19"
},
{
   _id:2,
   status:"inactive",
   sale:5,
   createdAt:"2019-10-08 02:01:19"
}]
```

I need to group it by "day".The result which I want

```
[{
  createdAt:"2019-10-08 02:01:19",
  inactive: 2,
  active:1,
  salesOfActive: 4,
  salesOfInactive:10
}]
```

I am not getting the actual result which I want any help will be highly appreciated

I had try with this but won't get an idea how i will get ***salesOfActive***  and ***salesOfInactive*** per day

```
{
        $group: {
          _id: {
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$createdAt" }
          },
          inActive:{$sum: { status:"inactive"}},
          active:{$sum: { status:"active"}},
          salesOfActive: { $sum:$sale  }
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you just want `salesOfActive` to reflect the sum of sale field? If so, what you have should work.

Comment: No, I want total in "saleOfInactive" where status ="inactive" and total in "saleOfActive" where status="active"

Comment: Ohh I see. So you may have multiple `inactive` or `active` entries on the same day, and you want to know how many sales... Hm you may need multiple stages for this I'll try a few things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) each field [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)itionally here

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$dayOfMonth": { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$createdAt" } }
    },
    "inactive": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$status", "inactive"] }, 1, 0] }
    },
    "active": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$status", "inactive"] }, 0, 1] }
    },
    "salesOfInactive": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$status", "inactive"] }, "$sale", 0] }
    },
    "salesOfActive": {
      "$sum": { "$cond": [{ "$eq": ["$status", "inactive"] }, 0, "$sale"] }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CG8OBB57sKC)

Comment: How to achieve this in Java?